# Type mapping of NUMERIC values from sql server JDBC driver

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

According to [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#setBigDecimal%28java.lang.String,%20java.math.BigDecimal%29):

> void setBigDecimal(String parameterName,
>                      BigDecimal x)
>                      throws SQLException
>   Sets the designated parameter to the given java.math.BigDecimal value. The driver converts this to
>   an SQL NUMERIC value when it sends it to the database.

I've some mssql `stored procedure`, that have in parameter of type `NUMERIC(10, 0)` and I try to pass this value as `java.math.BigDecimal` in JDBC ... But I got:

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Error converting data type decimal to numeric`

I do can found workarounds (ex. change the parameter type to `BIGING` and use `setLong` from Java)..

But My question is... is this bug in sql server jdbc driver?

Comment: The problem can arise when your `BigDecimal` doesn't fit in the `NUMERIC(10, 0)`.

Comment: Could you please post the code that raises your exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.lang.Long` might fit well here, however I think this is an issue in the mssql driver.